# Clarification on the Fundamental Counting Principle

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Here is an example question.

We have the word CHEMISTRY. What are the ways that we can have a **vowel** in the **second slot**.

Does the principle prioritize the vowel part first? In other words, would we assume FIRST that we have 2 possible ways to place a vowel in the second slot (since there are two vowels in the word), and place the remaining 8 letters OR start from the very first slot?

Comment: It's not the principle that is doing the work, it's you. The "principle" just tells you that if one event can happen $n$ ways and another event can happen in $m$ ways, then the number of ways both events can happen is $nm$. You have to decide which events you will consider and how to count the number of possible outcomes for them. Then the principle tells you to multiply your two counts to get the total number.

Comment: Yes, I was just using the principle as my method of working. However, I would assume that you prioritize the specific event first, then consider the rest?

Comment: You do one thing first, another thing second. You decide which you want to do first, usually in a way that simplifies the calculations. Nothing forces you to pick the vowel first... you can it in any way you want. It's just that picking the vowel in the second position first makes it easy to figure out the number of way of doing the rest, whereas picking the first letter means that you have to consider different cases for how many ways there are to complete the task. But the principle doesn't tell you to "prioritize" anything.

Comment: +1 to your posting.  In my opinion, the underlying question that you are asking is a deep one, that I might over-simplify as follows: if you have a (for example) probability (or enumeration) question that can either be attacked **directly**, or by alternate means (e.g. Inclusion-Exclusion or recursion) what is the easiest approach for the specific question?  In my experience, there is no hard and fast rule.  My general approach is to allocate about 3 minutes each, first considering the direct approach, then Inclusion-Exclusion, then recursion.  ...see next comment

Comment: Once I find an approach that looks promising, I immediately discard the alternatives and pursue that approach.  For this specific problem, given that there are only 2 vowels (or 3 vowels, if you count `Y`), and given that only the 2nd position has a constraint on it, it is obvious that the direct approach is easiest.  For example, you could assume that the 2nd letter is `E`, compute the enumeration, and then multiply the computation by either $~2~$ or $~3,~$ depending on whether `Y` is a vowel.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed explanation! Thank you so much - and yes, I don't consider Y a vowel here.